# Divisors of $x^3 + x + 1$ in $Z_3[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

Divisors of $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$ in $Z_3[x]$

Do I have to manually check whether each polynomial in $Z_3[x]$ with degree less than $3$ divides $f$ or is there a better way? That's $3^3 = 27$ polynomials to check (although a few are obviously trivial).

Comment: Long story short, if this factors, then it has a linear factor, and that means a root in $Z_3$. You only have to check three things. This trick can break down at degree $4$ though, because of the possibility of two quadratic irreducible factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: What is $f(1)$? That should get you a partial factorization, and make checking the rest quite a bit easier.

Bear in mind that $\Bbb Z_3$ is a field, so every non-zero constant is a divisor.

Comment: $f(1) = 0$, I don't see how that gives me a partial factorization?

Comment: Well, since $f(1)=0,$ then what must be a factor of $f(x)$?

Comment: $(x - 1) = (x + 2)$?

Comment: Yes! So you know that $$f(x)=(x-1)(x^2+ax+b)$$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb Z_3.$ Figure out what $a,b$ are, and then see if the quadratic can be factored.

Comment: Well I have $f(x) = (x + 2)(x^2 + x + 2)$. Now letting $g(x) = x^2 + x + 2$, there is no element $a$ in $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$ such that $g(a) = 0$. So g(x) can't be factored. So that just leaves me with the following divisors of $f$ - $\{1, f, (x + 2), (x^2 + x + 2)\}$. So we only have $4$ divisors?

Comment: Not quite. Bear in mind that $\Bbb Z_3$ is a field, so *every* non-zero constant is a divisor. I'm going to add that to my answer, actually.

Comment: So we also have $2(2x^3 + 2x + 1)$, giving us a final total of $6$ divisors?

Comment: We should have $8$ total. $f(x)=2(2x^3+2x+2)$ and $f(x)=(2x+1)(2x^2+2x+1).$

Comment: How did you determine that the last two are divisors?

Comment: I simply multiplied $x+2$ and $x^2+x+2$ by $2$. Since $2^2=1,$ then their product is exactly $f(x)$.

Comment: Ok, but how do you that is all the divisors of $f(x)$. Why would you not try multiplying multiplying more elements together?

Comment: @sonicboom Well, you know that $0$ isn't a divisor. Since you know that $f(0)\ne 0,$ then neither $x$ nor any of its multiples is a divisor. Likewise, neither $x-2$ nor any of its multiples is a divisor. A cubic can only be factored as: (1) a product of a constant and a cubic, (2) a product of a linear factor and a quadratic factor, (3) a product of three linear factors. Since $1,2$ are the only feasible constant factors and $x-1,2x+1$ are the only feasible linear factors (each with multiplicity $1$), then we're done.

Comment: @CameronBuie Cheers, very nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to check that many polynomials, for three reasons:

1. If a polynomial of degree $3$ has a factor of degree $2$, it also has a factor of degree $1$; in general, for a polynomial of degree $n$, the highest degree divisor you have to check is ${\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}$.
2. Because $\mathbb{F}_3$ is a field, every nonzero element has an inverse; so if you have a factor $ax+b$, you can rewrite this factor as $x+a^{-1}b$ and just check for factors of the form $x+c$. (Again, you can generalize this to higher degrees; you can always make the coefficient of the highest power of $x$ equal to $1$, and make checking for roots easier.
3. Lastly, if you want to see if $x+c$ divides your polynomial $f$, you can just check whether or not $f(-c)=0$.

If in step $3$, you find no linear factors, it's irreducible. If there's only one, then your polynomial is a product of a linear and irreducible quadratic factor, i.e., $f(x)=(x+a)(x^2+bx+c)$, where the latter polynomial is irreducible. And if you find two, your polynomial is completely reducible into linear factors, $f(x)=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$.

A word of warning on step $3$: That you can completely factor your polynomial just by finding linear factors stops working for any degree greater than $3$. Even if we step up into polynomials of degree $4$, we can't just check for linear factors; you can always do that, but your polynomial might be factored as $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$, so you'd have to check for quadratic factors too!